# Code runs just fine, where's the problem?

Tags: c

I got an assignment that says there's something wrong with the following code. I've been trying to figure it out for hours and I can't. It runs just fine and everything seems ok. Can you guys help me?
The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = {'H', 'i', ' ', 0};
    char str2[] = {'H', 'o', 0};

    strncat(str1, str2, strlen(str1) + strlen(str2));

    printf("%s", str1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: the concatenation is overwriting the bounds of `str1`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: You haven't allocated enough space for `str1` to accept any extra characters.  Also, using `strncat()` is error prone.  The length argument is not the length of the target buffer — it is the number of characters that can be added safely, not counting a terminal null.  Even if `str1` is empty, `strnchar*(str1, str2, sizeof(str1))` is a probable overwriting bug.  You have to subtract one from the size to be safe.  It's a good idea to end outputs with a newline: `printf("%s\n", str1);`.

Comment: "Runs fine" does not mean "bug free" or "devoid of undefined behaviour".

Comment: [Read a reference to the strcat function so you understand what it is supposed to do](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

Comment: `str1` is an array of 4 `char`s, but you are trying to store 6 `char`s in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior because you're writing past the end of your `str1` array.

You are encountering the worst possible outcome of undefined behavior -- your program seems to behave as you intended. That means you have a bug that's going to be difficult to track down, because it doesn't (necessarily) exhibit any symptoms.

On the machine level, what's probably happening is that there happens to be some unused memory space just after `str1`, and you're successfully writing data there. You might be stepping on the contents of `str2`, or on some system data that doesn't happen to be causing any visible problems.

C, as the saying goes, gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot. A lot of errors won't necessarily be caught either by the compiler or at run time. That places an extra burden on C programmers -- and on external tools. For example, a source-level debugger *might* help diagnose this kind of problem, but there are no guarantees.